# railsのsend_fileを使って画像をinline表示した際、IEで見れない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 画像, internet-explorer

下記のようなコードで画像を表示してるのですが、
IE(確認したのは9,11)でみるとバツが表示されてうまく表示できません。
対処策はありますか？

```
stat = File::stat filepath
send_file filepath, :filename => 'image.png', :length => stat.size, :disposition => 'inline'
```

Answer (score 1):

type (Content-Type) を渡していないようですが、送出しているコンテンツに合った Content-Type は出ているでしょうか。PNGであれば`:type => 'image/png'`を指定します。